# Can I add delay on gigabitEthernet type of interface (cisco switch)?

Tags: cisco

I learned that I could introduce delay on serial interface by using the command

```
      delay 'yyyyy'
```

Can I also do this if I am using gigabitEthernet interface?

Comment: Two questions. 1) why? 2) Try it and find out!

Comment: I have a network emulator but it's no longer working efficiently, I am looking for other ways in order to introduce delay to my network. I used that command already on my switch, but it did not affect the delay. I am wondering if there are other commands that I need to add.

Comment: You might want to look into [Dummynet](http://info.iet.unipi.it/~luigi/papers/20091201-dummynet.pdf) which is a full-featured link emulator. It also has [Linux](http://xmodulo.com/how-to-install-dummynet-on-centos.html) and [OS X](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man4/dummynet.4.html) ports, if you are not at ease with FreeBSD. Building a bridge with dummynet policies in between should allow you to define bandwidth restrictions as well as delay/loss parameters for your emulated link.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the model of a switch, but the short answer would be yes, but this wouldn't be that simple as you imagine because:

- delays are just the thing that modern networks are fighting with
- thus, you would need to simulate low link speed instead
- this is done by QoS, not rate-limiting, because rate-limiting is the primitive form of policing that would rather drop your packets than delay them
- QoS isn't supported just by every piece of a Cisco equipment, so it depends on the model

In the end this isn't that elementary.